# Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python'

Tags: python, django, web, vercel, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to deploy django web app through vercel. I have added django in requirements.txt file but it shows this error:

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': No module named 'django'`

Feel free to share if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The 'whitenoise' module is commonly used in Python web applications, particularly with Django, to serve static files efficiently. To resolve this issue,

Install the 'whitenoise' Module: Ensure that you have the 'whitenoise' module installed in your Python environment. You can do this using a package manager like pip:`pip install whitenoise`

Comment: adding whitenoise>=6.4.0 to requirements.txt not works for me